# Comparing equality of two lists of numbers in scheme

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

I'm currently learning scheme and I've come across an example question that has stumped me.
The situation is that you have numbers as lists. The number 2048 is (8 4 0 2), 399 is (9 9 3).
The problem is asking to compare the equality of these two lists and in this case list1 > list2.

My code so far:

```
 (define dl>
  (lambda (d1 d2)
    (if (> (length d2) (length d1))
        #f
    ;then
    (if (> (length d1) (length d2))
        #t   
   (let ((Rd1 (reverse d1)) (Rd2 (reverse d2)))
     (let loop((ls1 Rd1) (ls2 Rd2))
       (cond
         ((> (car ls1) (car ls2)) #t)
         ((and (= (car ls1) (car ls2)) (not (null? (cdr ls2))) (not (null? (cdr ls1)))) (loop (cdr ls1) (cdr ls2)))
         ((and (= (car ls1) (car ls2)) (null? (cdr ls2)) (null? (cdr ls1))) #f) ; dlnats are equal
         (else #f)                         
       )
     ))
   ))))
```

With my algorithm I have tried to start checking if the second list is greater in length (i.e. more digits) then this is not greater than because it is impossible so it returns false.

Then it checks if list1 is > list2. If so it is true because it is impossible for list2 to be > list1.

At this point in the code we can assume they are lists of the same length. Then I have reversed the lists. This is done so the most significant bit is first. Then looping through the two lists I have added checks each time it loops.

If the element in ls1 > ls2 then it should return true

If the elements are equal and the next value of both is not null then loop again

If the elements are equal and the next values are both null then the lists are equal and it should return false

At this point I really have no idea why the code is not working. It will work and give the correct output when the inputed strings are different in length but when they are in equal length I get the error: application:

not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: #t
  arguments...: [none]

Just wondering if anyone can spot anything critically wrong with the block of code where I'm looping because this seems to be the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `; then` comments should not have a preceding opening parenthesis.

Comment: Also, uncomment `(else #f)`.

Comment: ok I've done this please check the edit because i'm still getting the same error

Comment: I don't get any error now. With which parameters are you calling the procedure?

Comment: (dl> '(4 2 0 1) '(4 2 0 1)) to check that it should give #f for an equal. (dl> '(5 2 0 1) '(4 2 0 1)) to check that it should give #t. both give errors.

Comment: Both work correctly for me. You must have modified your code by mistake. Copy it back from your question, that's what I did.

Comment: @uselpa thats weird.. got it working perfectly now thanks. not sure if you want to answer it using your first two comments?

Comment: I don't have the time to give you a proper answer, which would include some refactoring of your code. Maybe somebody else will take the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two errors:

1. the `; then` comments should not have a preceding opening parenthesis
2. uncomment `(else #f)`

then it should work.

I would nevertheless suggest you simplified your code as follows:

```
(define (dl> d1 d2)
  (let ((len1 (length d1)) (len2 (length d2))) ; determine lengths only once
    (if (= len1 len2)
        (let loop ((ls1 (reverse d1)) (ls2 (reverse d2)))
          (if (null? ls1) ; or ls2, since they have the same length
              #f
              (let ((c1 (car ls1)) (c2 (car ls2)))
                (if (= c1 c2)
                    (loop (cdr ls1) (cdr ls2))
                    (> c1 c2)))))
        (> len1 len2))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(define (compare x y)
  (if (null? x)
    (if (null? y)
      '=
      '<)
    (if (null? y)
      '>
      (let ((rest-comparison (compare (rest x) (rest y))))
        (case rest-comparison
          ((=) (compare-number (first x) (first y)))
          (else rest-comparison))))))

(define (compare-number x y)
  (cond ((< x y) '<)
        ((> x y) '>)
        (else '=)))
```

Comment: Answers are always more helpful if they provide some explanation, rather than just code.